# How to Convert multivariate XTS to TS in R

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, xts, forecasting

I've already converted Sales_Data to xts and now want to convert to ts-in a time series  data as:

```
Sales_Data_xts<-xts(Sales_Data[, -1], order.by = as.POSIXct(Sales_Data$Month))
```

With the following argument below, I'm getting ending up with an error below:

```
frequency(Sales_Data_xts)

[1] Inf

Sales_Data_ts<-as.ts(Sales_Data_xts, start=start(Sales_Data_xts), end=end(Sales_Data_xts), frequency=frequency(Sales_Data_xts))
```

> Error in ts(coredata(x), frequency = frequency(x), ...) :    formal
>   argument "frequency" matched by multiple actual argument

I also tried to calculate the frequency as I have 2310 rows and 6 days as: 
frequency=2310/6=385, and used it as:

```
Sales_Data_ts<-as.ts(Sales_Data_xts, start=start(Sales_Data_xts), end=end(Sales_Data_xts), frequency=385)
```

But still the same error:

> Error in ts(coredata(x), frequency = frequency(x), ...) : 
>   formal argument "frequency" matched by multiple actual arguments

Please tell me how to convert `xts` to `ts`, so I can use the model for further time-series modelling. Thank you. Any solution for this will be appreciated.

Comment: can use `xts::as.timeSeries.xts(myxtsobject)`

Comment: What version of xts are you using? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616)?